# Extract files and folders from SharePoint 2013 document library to local folder

Tags: 2013, development, document-library, csom, ssom

We have a SharePoint document library inside SharePoint 2013 on-premises. the document library contains around 1 TB of files and folders. now we want to extract those files and folders from SharePoint 2013 to local folder? so is there any server-side code, client side code or Power shell code i can use to copy those files and folders and preserve the folder structure and preserve the files and folders metadata such as Createdby,Modifiedby,Created & Modified will be nice to have ?